# Invalid credentials even after a successful refresh token on first time load angularjs

Tags: angularjs, google-calendar-api

I am trying to integrate google calendar api in my angularjs spring mvc application.I am able to connect to google and get all the events from the calendar.First time i am getting one access token and same access token i am storing into database.After one hour the token is getting expired and i am posting to google token endpoint by sending refresh token and getting new access token like this.

```
    $scope.checkAccessTokenExpiry = function(){
    AccountSettingService.checkAccessTokenExpiry().then(function(response){
        $scope.difference = response.data;
        var refresh_token = $scope.loginuser.refreshToken;
        var tokenExpiry = $scope.difference;
        var client_id = my client_id;
        var client_secret = client_secret;
        var grant_type = 'refresh_token';

        if(tokenExpiry>50){
            $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token?
                  client_id='+my client id+'&client_secret='+client_secret+'&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token='+refresh_token+'',
         headers: {
                      ContentType: 'application/json'
                  },

                  success: function(result) {
                      var access_token = result.access_token;
          AccountService.saveToken(access_token).then(function(response){
                            if(response!=null){
                        alert("saved"); 
                    }
                    });
                   },
                  processData: false,
                });
               }
    });
    }

    $interval( function(){ $scope.checkAccessTokenExpiry; }, 3300000, true);
```

I am calling this $scope.checkAccessTokenExpiry() function in ng-init on page load.Everything is working but after one hour the previous token expires and if i go to calendar then it shows invalid credentials error even though i am loading method on load.After i refresh the same page then again everything works fine.Here i am calling google token endpoint if the previous access token duration is greater than 50 minutes.But at first this doesnt seem to be called.Only after refresh it seems to work.After one hour if i am in any other tab and if i toggle to calendar tab it displays error.If i refresh then it works fine displaying events.Why doesnt it work the first time although i am loading the method onload?Is there any other way to handle this so that everytime it checks the condition and if it satisfies the condition i can store new access token without refreshing the page because now for first time after 1 hour it doesnt work?

Comment: As you mentioned you are calling "checkAccessTokenExpiry" in "ng-init" then it will be called only once at the time of initialization of element on which it is written. But what I can understand from your requirement is that you need to trigger "checkAccessTokenExpiry" at regular intervals so make use of $interval service.

Comment: Do i have to use watchers concept?

Comment: Even if i use $intervalService it is also working after i refresh once

Comment: Have you verified if the callback passed to $interval is getting called at regular intervals, if yes then please verify the "if(tokenExpiry>50)" condition that might coming out to be false. If everything works fine please share your code via plnkr, jsfiddle if possible

Comment: Can you please tell how to use callback for the above mentioned code?

Comment: I have updated my question.I have used $interval at the last and called $scope.checkAccessTokenExpiry function after every 55 minutes.So that function will be called after every 55 minutes.but nothing is working

Comment: If(tokenExpiry>50) is working fine.If token duration is more than 55 minutes then it is coming inside the condition.But problem is after it comes inside i am doing  post request to google api.After i get new access token i am saving it to database.But this part doesnt seem to work on first load.After refreshing all these things work

Comment: Please help me on callback function for above code or is there any alternative for calling a method asynchronously for every 50 minutes without refreshing the page